# определенный скролл, анимация при скролле

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, css-animation

нужен примерно такой скроллинг как показанно здесь, http://luminouspil.com/#, я использовал инструмент snap-scroll, но не получил то что ожидал, на сайте, который указал выше, при любом размере прокрутки страница скроливается на определенные точки, а на моем примере если слишком прокрутит то пропускается определенный блок ․․․ структура у меня такой

```
<div>
 <section></section>
 <section></section>
 <section></section>
 <section></section>
 <section></section>
</div>
```

ссылка на мой проект оставлю в гугл диске - https://drive.google.com/file/d/12e1y6xR3VMCcBA5yVMe8Bst3k-IxVH9v/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Вызов elem.scrollIntoView(boolean) прокручивает страницу, чтобы elem оказался вверху или внезу. Как аргумент true false ... true не обязательно

Answer (score 0):

как не доработанный пример только для демонстрации работы

```
let sec = document.querySelector('div')
let d = 0
setInterval(() => {
  d++
}, 3000);
document.addEventListener('scroll',e => {
  sec.children[d].scrollIntoView()
})
```